# based on logged in user i want to hide or show some of action views

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net core application consists of several controllers and action methods...so based on logged in user i want to hide or show the some of controller action views
for ex:if logged in user is admin i want to allow total access
other then admin i want to restrict some views from them..

I was using [Authorize(Roles = "")] on controller action method it is hiding from all the users including admin

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You can control it in layout.cshtml, with the if conditions on roles. If condition satisfies then only show those blocks or button that will redirect to your particular views or actions.

Comment: Yes iam using Tempdata["userrole"]="admin" in view. but it is working only for one view ..how to pass  Tempdata["userrole"] through out the application ??is i need to use any other session state variables??

Comment: Yes, you would need a `Session` variable to store your role and then use it through out the application until the `Session` is destroyed.Something like this in your _Layout page : `@if (@Context.Session.GetString("Role").Equals("admin") {//show admin view} else {//show some other view})`

Comment: If you are using identity then you can fetch like this User.Identity.GetUserRoles(); otherwise fetch the roles from database and pass them to a view in a Model or save roles into session and destroy it when logout.